# How can I create a Bluemix service via the Cloud Foundry CLI when there are spaces in the plan name?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, personality-insights

I am currently trying to create the Watson Personality Insights service in my Bluemix org via the Cloud Foundry CLI. However, the service plan available has spaces in it, causing my command to be misinterpreted. My command id as follows:

```
$ cf create-service personality_insights IBM Watson Personality Insights Monthly Plan personality-insights-box
```

I have tried concatenating the plan name with plus signs, hyphens, and underscores to no avail. Can someone please let me know if this is even possible and if so, how I would do it?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use escape characters to mark that you are using space literals in your command. The correct command is as follows:

```
$ cf create-service personality_insights IBM\ Watson\ Personality\ Insights\ Monthly\ Plan personality-insights-box
```

Comment: you can also use single or double quotes if you are on UNIX/Linux.